# Can we use npm packages in cocos-creator?

Tags: npm, cocoscreator

I would like to use npm packages like moment, lodash, axios etc. in cocos creator.

Is it possible to use them via `npm i --package-name`?

Are there any restrictions to use them in cocos? I couldn't find any information in cocos docs, if there is any information that you know how cocos approach to npm packages please share a link or give information about their vision.

Answer (score 2):

You can open cocos-creator project like any other project in any code editor from where you can manage your dependencies.

From what I understand you just need to do the following:

1. `npm init` in root creator-project directory.
2. Install packages you want to use.
3. Use `require` on any cocos-creator script.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You can install node packages.

[npm location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9D7g.png)

Then, use import or require

[import package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cmWWR.png)

Comment: Please improve your answer by reading [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).